# Batch file script to folder in zip files

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder structure in this pattern. I've just shown two sub directories and 2 files in each but generally I have n number of subdirectories at a single level and single level of files (but can be n number of files or folders)under them.

```
Directory master
folder 1:
  file1
  file2
folder 2:
  file 3
  file 4
  folder x
```

I need to create a windows script, a batch file to run from the master directory and give me two zip files x.zip and y.zip containing their respective files.

```
1.zip (only contains file1 and file2 -without folder 1 )
2.zip (only contains file3 and file4 and folder x -without folder 2- )
```

the zip file dont be contain the folder 1 or folder 2

this code do it, but compress to ther subfolder  as
 1.zip (
           folder 1
               file1
               file2
       )
 2.zip (
       folder 2(
                file3 
                file4 
                folder x
             )
       )

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (ECHO zip -r -p "%%~na.zip" ".\%%a\*")
```

Comment: Could you tell me what is the software that you use to zip in ECHO zip -r -p "%%~na.zip" ".\%%a\*" command?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can achieve what you want with the below code which uses 7-zip to zip files:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set YOUR_DIR=%1
set OWNING_DIR=%~dp0
set zipext=.zip

for /f "tokens=*" %%L in ('dir /b "%YOUR_DIR%"' ) do (
   set FOLDER_NAME=%%L
     set zipname=%OWNING_DIR%\!FOLDER_NAME!%zipext%
     set ERRORLEVEL=0
     type NUL
     set DIR_TO_CHECK=%YOUR_DIR%\!FOLDER_NAME!
     IF EXIST "!DIR_TO_CHECK!"\* (
       pushd %YOUR_DIR%\!FOLDER_NAME! >NUL 2>&1
       if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
         for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ( 'dir /b') do (
            "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a  "!zipname!" "%%a"             
          )
       )
       popd
      ) 
   )
```

Copy this to a batch file called zip_files.bat and call it using

```
zip_files "Directory_master"
```

Comment: Where does the original post say that 7Zip is being used? The question asks about a batch file, not about recommendations on how to do it in other software via a batch file. Your answer is the equivalent of someone asking how to do something in a Windows batch file and you answering *Well, on OSX you could...*. It doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: My answer is a batch file script and it just used 7-zip to zip files. OP wanted to know how it could be done with a batch file! Where did I recommend not to use batch file?

Comment: Read what I wrote again. The question does not ask *How can I zip these files by installing some other third-party software first?*. It does not use 7Zip, and therefore a solution using 7Zip does not answer the question asked. Give the same batch file example (without requiring the OP to install additional software), and I'll remove my objection.